# How to run adobe photoshop cs4 on wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adobe-photoshop, linux-mint, wine

I dual booted my xp installing linux mint 12. I have photoshop cs4 installed on xp, but can't run it on wine. Why?

Comment: What does it mean when you say you "*can't run it on wine*"?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I select `open photoshop.exe using wine` and nothing happens, wine tries to open it, but it does not, therefore nothing happens

Comment: Do you get any error?  Have you run an installer for Photoshop CS4 in WINE, or are you just running the .exe file?  From what the WINE appdb shows, you may have to export registry keys from Windows and add them to WINE: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14318&iTestingId=58699

Comment: @AdamThompson I did not have any error, nothing happens, i'm trying to run photoshop.exe on wine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) which is an open source app - and install PS from there

[image]

Comment: Important to note... he said to **INSTALL PHOTOSHOP** from this program.  He did not say to just try to run it.  Just to be clear,, it appears you will have to install Photoshop through a windows emulator onto your installation of Linux, rather than just trying to run the Windows installation of Photoshop.  Why?  Well, there are portions of PS CS4 all over the installation of Windows, and only the Windows Registry knows where they are.  Linux is only going to have access to all those necessary pieces if you install it FROM Linux.

Comment: hey jet, thank you for telling me about playonlinux, i did not know about this tool before now